# Adding labels to both ends of axis google charts

Tags: reactjs, charts, google-visualization, bubble-chart

I've built a bubble chart on quadrant graph using google-charts in reactjs but I can only had two labels on my axis and I need four.

I've tried fiddling with the code but unsuccessfully. I don't want to append dummy data and additional series elements. Is overlay the only option to add axis?

```
<Chart
  width={"800px"}
  height={"600px"}
  chartType="BubbleChart"
  loader={<div>Loading Chart</div>}
  data={[
    ["Age", "Weight", "4", "Group", "Size"],
    ["Name", -12, 34, 1, 7],
    ["Name", -5.5, 6, 1, 8],
    ["Name", 22, 35, 1, 4],
    ["Name", 14, 4, 2, 5],
    ["Name", -5, -5, 2, 6],
    ["Name", 15, 34, 3, 1],
    ["Name4", 7, -21, 4, 22]
  ]}
  options={{
    bubble: {},
    chartArea: { left: 20, top: 0, width: "90%", height: "95%" },
    colors: ["red", "green", "yellow", "blue"],
    hAxis: {
      title: "Low Importance",
      ticks: "none",
      baseline: 0,
      ticks: ["none"],
      minValue: -50,
      gridlines: { count: 0 },
      maxValue: 50
    },
    vAxis: {
      title: "Low Urgency",
      baseline: 0,
      ticks: ["none"],
      minValue: -50,
      gridlines: { count: 0 },
      maxValue: 50
    },
    legend: "none"
  }}
/>;
```

As you can see in the graph below, I can only get left and bottom labels but not top and right. Any ideas how I could achieve that using google-chart library for reactjs?

[image]

Comment: there are no options out of the box to add additional labels. overlays, or adding elements to the chart, are the only option. though not react, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56650616/5090771) is an example, which could be implemented in the same manner, using the `'ready'` event...